# How to call other component function from different component?

Tags: javascript, angular

I've html structure like this :

Parent Component where both `Comp1` and `Comp2` resides :

now in `comp1` I've some elements if that changes then I've to reflect values in `comp2` but there's no connection between them.

**Comp1 :**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Comp2Component } from 'comp2.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'comp1',
  templateUrl: './comp1.html'
})
export class Comp1Component {

    sortBy(value)
    {
        this.FeedSortBy = value;
        this.SortByLabel = this.SortByLabelList[value];
        Comp2Component.filterActivities();
    }
}
```

**Comp2**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
      selector: 'comp2',
      templateUrl: './comp2.html'
    })
    export class Comp2Component {

     filterActivities()
     {
         //call this function on comp1 sort function call so it will update value of comp2
     }

  }
```

As per Rahul and Sajit's answer I try using with EventEmitter and change my structure to parent child :

In my parent component I use :

```
import { Component,EventEmitter, Input, Output, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { FeedsComponent } from '../feeds/feeds.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-desk',
  styleUrls: ['../../assets/css/style.min.css'],
  templateUrl: './my-desk.component.html'
})
export class MyDeskComponent {

    @Output() FeedSortBy = new EventEmitter<string>();
    sortBy(value)
    {
        this.FeedSortBy.emit(value);
    }
}
```

and in my child component I use :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

import { DataService } from '../data.service';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'feeds',
  styleUrls: ['../../assets/css/style.min.css'],
  templateUrl: './feeds.component.html'
})
export class FeedsComponent {
    constructor(private dataService:DataService)
    {

    }
    @Input() FeedSortBy:number = 2;
}
```

Child component HTML :

```
{{FeedSortBy}}
```

But it always output 2 it doesn't change can I get any trigger as well to know if value is change so I call function there

Comment: FYI. I removed the PHP tag, since this question isn't related to PHP in any way.

Comment: if the components are of a parent/child relationship, use EventEmitters, if not use a service to pass data between the 2. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: I second that what @SimonBriggs has said. You need to use Shared Services as given in the link that he has provided/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call method of another component from a different component but it will not update the value of the calling component without some tweaking like 
`Event Emitters` if they have a parent child relationship or `Shared Services` or using `ngrx redux pattern`

How to Call a different component method be like

Component1

```
  test(){
    console.log("Test");
  }
```

Component 2

```
  working(){
    let component = new Component1();
    component.test();
  }
```

Now to update the value in component 2 you might have to use any of the above.

For Event Emitters follow this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/inout)

For Shared services follow this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq)

For ngrx follow this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx)

Comment: Hi, I updated my question with example of EventEmitter but still not getting any value is there any way to get trigger when value updated ?

Comment: @MohitBumb that is not the correct way to use event emitters m please take a look at the above links and the corresponding git code

Comment: One important note even if you use correct syntax do these components have parent child relation i donot thing they have , you might need to use shared services  or ngrx @MohitBumb

Comment: thanks mate for link and examples its working fine now :)

Answer (score 4):

You **`cannot`** do that, There are two possible ways you could achieve this,

1. use **[`angular service`](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)** to pass the data between two components
2. use **[`Event Emitters`](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)** to pass the value among the components.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question with example of EventEmitter but still not getting any value is there any way to get trigger when value updated ?

Comment: http://www.fullstacktraining.com/articles/how-to-work-with-event-emitters-in-angularjs